# How to use a Gitlab artefact generated in one job as part of a rule in another job?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

**Context**

It is possible to save a stdout as an artifact and pass it to another job:

```
stages:
    - stage1
    - stage2

stage1:
    stage: stage1
    ...
    script:
        ...
        ...
        - echo "$(yq ".[].metadata | select(.name == \"$ARGOCD_APP_NAME\")" $HELM_APP_ARGOCD)" > build.env
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - build.env

stage2:
    stage: stage2
    ...
    script:
        - cat build.env
        ...
    needs:
        - job: stage1
          artifacts: true
```

**Question**

However, I would need to be able to use that artifact in a `rule` to be able to review the content. Any suggestions?

**Update**

Since the answer has been accepted, I did not want to close the question without making it clear how the issue was solved.

1. An environment variable associated with a dotenv artifact has been created to pass between jobs. E.g.:

```
job1:
  stage: stage1
  tags:
    - ...
  only:
    - pipelines
  script:
    ...
    ...
  after_script:
    ...
    ...
    - export SKIP_JOB=$(yq ".[].metadata | select(.name == \"$ARGOCD_APP_NAME\")" $HELM_APP_ARGOCD)
    - |- 
        if [[ $SKIP_JOB != '' ]]; then
            echo "SKIP_JOB=True" >dotenv.env
        else
            echo "SKIP_JOB=False" >dotenv.env
        fi
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: dotenv.env
```

2. `exit 0` directive used to skip job execution without failure. E.g.:

```
job2:
  stage: stage2
  tags:
    - ...
  only:
    - pipelines
  script:
    - |- 
        if [ "$SKIP_JOB" == "True" ]; then
          echo "This job is skipped based on the condition"
          exit 0
        else
          echo "This job is running"
        fi
    ...
    ...
  needs:
    - job: job1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently not possible.

You could have used the specific [dotenv](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/artifacts_reports.html#artifactsreportsdotenv) artifact type which then makes the content available as env variables.

But:

> You cannot use dotenv variables created in job scripts in rules, because rules are evaluated before any jobs run.
>
> - Source: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules

You have to implement this in the job itself but not via `rules`.